# Representing python dictionary in pictorial form

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, matplotlib, reinforcement-learning

I need a way to represent a dictionary (or NumPy 2D array) in pictorial form, perhaps something as pictured below.

[Q-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHYvf.png)

My dictionary currently looks like this
`Q: {(0,'U'): -0.1, (0,'R'): -0.254, (0,'D'): -0.9, (0,'L'): -0.23, ...}` where U, R, D, L corresponds to the direction, Up, Down, Right & Left

For additional context, I wish to visualize the Q-table for the SARSA learning method. I am running this in a Jupyter notebook.
I am running SARSA over a total of 100k episodes & would want to visualize the Q-table every 10k episode ran.

I suppose matplotlib might be able to do this? But I am not very familiar with this particular type of representation.

If anyone might know of better ways to represent the Q-table (as opposed to this particular pictorial format), I am open to suggestions. I can also represent the Q-table as a 2D numpy array instead of a dictionary if using a 2D array would be better.

Thanks in advance for any responses!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really know what a Q-table is, but I do spend a lot of time trying to visualize different things.

Based on my understanding of your problem, you need 10 tables which I've arranged in a 2 row by 5 column lattice in the code below. That said, this code should scale to whatever number you need, I hope.

I've created a dictionary of what I think are representative values for what might be in a Q-table? Hopefully my assumptions are close enough that you can use the code below to push your problem across the finish line.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n_row = 2 # number of rows
n_col = 5 # number of columns

# Make up some dummy data
Q = {}
for m in range(n_row * n_col):
    Q[(m, 'U')] = 2 * np.random.random() - 1
    Q[(m, 'D')] = 2 * np.random.random() - 1
    Q[(m, 'L')] = 2 * np.random.random() - 1
    Q[(m, 'R')] = 2 * np.random.random() - 1


# Plotting paramters:
boxsize = 0.5 # box size in inches
fontcol = 'k' # color of your U/D/L/R values
centerfontcol = [0.3, 0.3, 0.3] # color of the box number in the center
fontsize = 4   # font size to use

maxalpha = 0.3 # just to make boxes different backgrounds as per your
               # example if you want them all white, then remove this
               # and the "fill" command below

# Create a figure. Note that the "figsize" command gives yout the dimensions of
# your figure, in inches
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (n_col * boxsize, n_row * boxsize))

# This creates an axes for plotting. If you imagine your figure
# "canvas" as having normal coordinates where the bottom left is (0,0)
# and the top right is (1,1), then the line below gives you an axis
# that fills the entire area. The values give [Left, Bottom,
# Width, Height].
ax = plt.axes([0, 0, 1, 1])

# These are spacings from the edges of each table used in setting the
# text
xspace = 0.2 / n_col
yspace = 0.15 / n_row


m = 0 # m is a counter that steps through your tables

# When stepping through each table, we set things up so that the
# limits of the figure are [0, 1] in the x-direction and the
# y-direction so values are normalized

for r in range(n_row):
    # top and bottom bounds of the table
    y1 = 1 - (r + 1) / n_row  
    y2 = 1 - r / n_row
    for c in range(n_col):
        # left and right bounds of the table
        x1 = c / n_col
        x2 = (c+1) / n_col

        # plot the box for the table
        plt.plot([x1, x1, x2, x2, x1], [y1, y2, y2, y1, y1], 'k')

        # fill the box for the table, if you want
        # fillalpha is just if you want the boxes different shades
        fillalpha = maxalpha * np.random.random()
        plt.fill([x1, x1, x2, x2, x1], [y1, y2, y2, y1, y1], 'k', alpha = fillalpha)

        # Put the values in
        # center
        plt.text((x1 + x2) / 2, (y1 + y2) / 2, "%i" % m,
                 color = centerfontcol, fontsize = fontsize, va = 'center', ha = 'center')

        # left
        plt.text(x1 + xspace, (y1 + y2) / 2, "%.2f" % Q[(m, 'L')],
                 color = fontcol, fontsize = fontsize, va = 'center', ha = 'center')
        # right
        plt.text(x2 - xspace, (y1 + y2) / 2, "%.2f " % Q[(m, 'R')],
                 color = fontcol, fontsize = fontsize, va = 'center', ha = 'center')

        # up
        plt.text((x1 + x2) / 2, y2 - yspace, "%.2f" % Q[(m, 'U')],
                 color = fontcol, fontsize = fontsize, va = 'center', ha = 'center')

        # down
        plt.text((x1 + x2) / 2, y1 + yspace, "%.2f" % Q[(m, 'D')],
                 color = fontcol, fontsize = fontsize, va = 'center', ha = 'center')
        
        # augment the counter
        m += 1
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.savefig("q-table.png", bbox_inches = "tight")
```

[image: Example q-table]

Comment: hey thanks a lot! this worked for me :)
I just placed this inside a helper function & edited the rows & columns to suit my usecase!

Comment: just a question, I saw the fill function & it'll be useful as I wish to only color certain cells in the table with the same grey/black color, how do I go about doing that? 

I have a list containing specific cells that I can pass in to the helper function I placed your code in. I know this needs to be passed into plt.fill() but could you quickly just show me with an example?

Let's say, boxes_to_color = [3, 5, 7]

Comment: If I understand you right, you have a function call that does each box? If that's the case you can just have an argument at the end with a default value (e.g. `fill_color = None`) then in the function, `if fill_color is not None: plt.fill(....., color = fill_color)`.

Comment: hey it's okay i got it! `m` tracks the index of the dictionary. I wanted to only color boxes with index that are from `holes`. I tried doing `if (r*n_row+c*n_col) in holes` but the wrong indexed boxes get colored somehow.